# python packaging: Building cross-platform package versions using `conda` and Travis CI

Tags: python, build, anaconda, conda, travis-ci

This is one part of the package building pipeline that is still confusing for me. So, I am building a package using `conda` for `conda-forge`. Now I want to build the package for different platforms, so that it runs on Windows, Linux, and MacOS. This is just a python source package, so no need to compile anything.

So I know that in the `conda build` tool, I can specify the `conda_build_config.yaml` and that will indicate the python versions to use. So I can run `conda build .` and it will use the matrix from `conda_build_config.yaml` and create the different versions for upload to my anaconda.org channel.

But the other thing is [Travis CI and its ability to create package builds](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/use-conda-with-travis-ci.html#building-a-conda-recipe). So it seems like Travis can also create separate builds for different versions of the package. And in the Travis `.travis.yml` file, I also specify different python versions and platforms.

So my goal again, is just to test the package on each platform/python version, and then create builds for each variant. What is the right division of labor between what `conda_build_config.yaml` and `.travis.yml`? Meaning that could I just remove the python versions from the `conda_build_config.yaml` and specify them in the `.travis.yml` file, and get all of the versions built. Or it seems like specifying the python versions and platforms in both files will just generate every single variant twice? So that is my confusion.

So what is the most efficient way to execute these types of source builds for all platforms and python versions. Thanks.

Comment: If it really is platform-independent, then [a `noarch` build](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#noarch-builds) might be worth looking into.

Comment: @merv thanks for the info. The problem is that some dependencies rely on `gdal` C++, and those `gdal` packages are provided with source and not binaries. Otherwise I would have tried `noarch` as you said. Now you certainly know packaging better than I do. Given this info, can I still use `noarch` or do I need to do something different?

Comment: Not sure. If they are runtime dependencies and not build dependencies, I would still expect that `noarch` would be appropriate.

Comment: @merv Thanks for the tip. Yeah, I am going to hunt through some of the conda-forge recipes that have something like `rasterio` as a dependency and see how they handled it. You are totally right, if I can get away with `noarch` then that would solve things, right.